# TextFiled border disappear when click it flutter

Tags: flutter

Here my style of my textfiled and when ever i click to write the border is disappear

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: white,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          hintText: (hintText),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 23, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: white),
```

Comment: Do you have a white background ?

Comment: @ikerfah no my background is dark blue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set `focusedBorder` as well for `InputDecoration`.

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    ),
  ),
);
```